# $_FILES['image']['type'] not filtering properly

Tags: php, file-upload

My english not so good, sorry.

I am working with PHP language and am having problem with profile image upload
My code filters images based on type yet on server I have files that are not of accepted types, always from same IP.

I think it is because of my type checking but am not sure. Please help!

```
$bild = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
if (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $bild) {
    mysqli_laden($_FILES);
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.files.php#109902) helps: "Don't ever trust `$_FILES["image"]["type"]`. It takes whatever is sent from the browser, so don't trust this for the image type.  I recommend using [finfo_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that mysqli_laden is a custom function that uploads to server. Be careful when using $_FILES["image"]["type"] as it gets its information from the browser rather than the file itself. You should use the far more reliable finfo_open function which will verify the MIME type of a file. Check it out here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

Your code would look something like this

```
$bild = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
$image = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$image_inf = $finfo->file($image);

if (in_array($image_inf, $bild) {
    mysqli_laden($_FILES);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not sure but I thought it was `$finfo->file(FILEINFO_MIME, $image);`

Comment: @putvande: No. http://us1.php.net/finfo_file or `$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$image_inf = $finfo->file($image);`